# Auth::attempt() always return false, helpp

Tags: laravel

I was create api for login / register and create custom authentication for my laravel app, but i got problem. Auth attempt always return false, i already check my code, but feeling that's correct.

Please check my code :

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginValidation;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    function index() {
       return view('auth.login');
    }

    function login(LoginValidation $data) {
       dd($data->all());
       if (Auth::attempt(['EMAIL' => $data->email, 'PASSWORD' => $data->password])) {          
          if (Auth::user()->IS_VERIFIED == 1) {     

             return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Authentikasi berhasil' 
             ], 200); 

          } else {

             Auth::logout();

             return response()->json([
                 'message' => 'Authentikasi gagal, silahkan verifikasi email terlebih dahulu'
             ], 401);

          }

       } else {

          return response()->json([
             'message' => 'Authentikasi gagal, email atau password salah'
          ], 401);

       }
    }
}
```

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use App\User;
use App\Mail\EmailConfirmation;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterValidation;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    protected $token;

    function index() {
       return view('auth.register');
    }

    function register(RegisterValidation $data) {       
       $user = new User;
       $user->NAME = $data->name;
       $user->EMAIL = $data->email;
       $user->PASSWORD = Hash::make($data->password);
       $user->REGISTRATION_DATE = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
       $user->VERIFICATION_KEY = $this->generateToken();
       $user->IS_VERIFIED = 0;
       $user->save();  

       Mail::to($data->email)->send(new EmailConfirmation($this->token));

       return response()->json([
           'message' => 'Pendaftaran berhasil silahkan cek email anda untuk verifikasi akun'
       ]);
    }

    function generateToken() {
       $this->token = str_random(50);

       return $this->token;
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'USER_TBL';

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Please helpp, Every answer will be appreciated

Comment: No answer here :(

Comment: Why you have all the filed wth uppercase? I think that is the problem

Comment: @Bak87 because the table column named that

Comment: @Bak87 but thanks, this problem already solved